# How do I launch a .jar file GUI from the command line?

Tags: java, macos, bash, user-interface, jar

I'm trying to write a quick script to launch a couple of (3rd party) .jar files. Normally I would navigate to the folder and double click the files individually which brings up a GUI.

When I run `java -jar [filename].jar` it doesn't open the GUI and instead runs as a command line app. Which makes sense I guess.

Is there any way to force it to open the GUI when running on the command line?

I'm using a Mac.

Thanks!

Comment: There should be a manifest file inside the jar that specifies what main method is ran. If it isn't a GUI, then I'm not sure what you expected to happen

Comment: You can rename a jar to a zip file and extract and browse it freely. I think `vim file.jar` also works

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking on a .jar file on a Mac runs the .jar via an app hidden in a system folder called Jar Launcher.

To simulate the double click from the command line you can run the Jar Launcher and pass it the .jar file as a parameter.

`open /System/Library/CoreServices/Jar\ Launcher.app ~/Path/to/JarFile.jar`

No idea why or how the .jar was showing different behaviour from double clicking when running with `java -jar` but this fixes it (on a Mac at least).